# numpy generates an error in PythonTeX

Tags: pythontex

**My question : How come PythonTex works as long as I don't try to load numpy ?**

In the simple code below for instance

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}

def fib(n): # nth Fibonacci value
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
\end{pycode}

Did you know that $F_{10} = \py{fib(10)}$?

Did you know that $F_{100} = \py{fib(100)}$?

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

whereas I get

[image]

When I use

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
%import numpy as np %<- I get an error each time I try to load `numpy`
def fib(n): # nth Fibonacci value
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
\end{pycode}

Did you know that $F_{10} = \py{fib(10)}$?

Did you know that $F_{100} = \py{fib(100)}$?

\end{document}
```

I compile on Windows 10, TeXmaker, MikteX, Anaconda and run

```
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
python "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py" %.tex|
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Reading multiple posts on PythonTeX I understand the answer might be related to my MikTeX and/or Python installation? But strange it works for simple things and creates an error for numpy...

**Edit**

As mentionned in comment, there might be a problem to find python.tex.
So I inputed the full path to python.exe directly in cmd but I get the following error message you might understand better than I do :/

[image]

Comment: You should have different versions of Python installed. One version sees numpy whereas the other not. Am I right?

Comment: @ projetmbc You seem to have a cristal ball !! Your comment made me try a `where python` and bingo You're right. I get two entries :/ Especially a `AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` I was not aware of !!

Comment: You need now to tell to pythontex which version to use. The documentation should explain how to do that.

Comment: @projetmbc Right ! I need to get rid of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor)

Comment: @projetmbc I've just tried to point things to the right python installation as in 
`pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
C:\tools\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py" %.tex|
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` but I still get an error.

Comment: @projetmbc Following your judicious comment I ran directly in cmd the path and got an error message you might understand better than me (i edited my question with a log)

Comment: It is late in France.   Try to show the message on a Python forum. Your problem seems to be Windows specific. I have to sleep.

Comment: @projetmbc Merci ! à bientot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After different checks and thanks to [this post](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1406) and [how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an).

This error occurs when using python3.9 and numpy1.19.4 So uninstalling numpy1.19.4 and installing 1.19.3 will work.

`pip install numpy==1.19.3`

And I get the right result loading numppy

[image]